# Navigation is not working with Default Route table in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an ASP.NET WebApplication with Internet Template.

I have **NOT** modified anything in the **RouteConfig class**, meaning I am using default Route table only.

When I type the following URL insde the browser

```
http://localhost:8416/
```

**Index view** is retuning insde **HomeController** without any problem.

But, if I type the following URL

```
http://localhost:8416/EstimationTracker/
```

I am gettinger the following error.

**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden**

**The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.**

But, if I type the following URL, view is returning fine (just appending **/Index** to the above URL).

```
http://localhost:8416/EstimationTracker/Index
```

My doubt is why **Index** action method is being not recognized as the default action method inside **EstimationTracker** controller or is something else happening?

For easy referece, the following is the code inside inside RouteConfig.cs file.

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EstimationTracker** folder created in the project root folder is causing the problem.

The error in the question means that the static file handler took the request.

I got the answer from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1912677.aspx/1?Navigation%20is%20not%20working%20with%20Default%20Route%20table%20in%20MVC%204).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a folder called EstimationTracker in you application's root folder?

Comment: The web server first try to serve the request without any application. So if there is a folder then it wants to display the contents of that folder. If there is none it pass the request to the extensionless handler. So before downvote think.

Comment: Okay. EstimationTracker folder is existing inside application's root folder. Now, suggest me solution. I hope you know the fact that if I mark your reply as Answer, the down-vote will erase off.

Comment: You have to rename the folder or the controller or move the folder into another one. I think there aren't any other solution.